# How to get the substring before & after a seperator?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-community

The Product name consists of a *string - number* like:

> Chains-23x10 5R 12

I want to display the **substring** before `-` in one line and the **substring** after `-` in next line. I tried it with the code:

```
<?php $str = substr($str, ($pos = strpos($str, '-')) === false ? 0 : $pos + 1); ?>
<?php echo $str; ?>
```

But only the string after `-` is getting displayed.

Someone help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code (Tested & Working):

```
$str = "Chains-23x10 5R 12"; // Pass Product name here
$strArr = explode("-", $str);
//print_r($strArr);
if(count($strArr) == 2){
    echo $strArr[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $strArr[1];
}else{
    echo $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the default *php explode* feature:

```
$str = 'Chains-23x10 5R 12';
$strParts = explode('-', $str);
print_r($strParts);

echo '<br/>';

echo 'Part 1: ' . (isset($strParts[0]) ? $strParts[0] : ' empty ');
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Part 2: ' . (isset($strParts[1]) ? $strParts[1] : ' empty ');
echo '<br/>';
echo 'Part 3: ' . (isset($strParts[2]) ? $strParts[2] : ' empty ');
```

The result should be the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hold **product name** in a variable and then use **`explode`** php function to explode name with **`-`**.

For example:

```
$productName = 'Chains-23x10 5R 12';
$arr = explode('-',$productName);

echo $arr[0];

echo $arr[1];
```

If there can be more than 1 -, then you can loop through $arr array.

Comment: See my updated question

Comment: Please check my updated answer.